# Right mouse button skips each 2nd click when CorelDRAW is running

Tags: mouse, right-click, mouse-click, coreldraw, mouse-buttons

After I start CorelDRAW x6 the right mouse button works every other time (I hit the button twice, but the PC behaves as if I hit it only once). This behaviour is the same whether CorelDRAW window is active or not. The problem disappears after closing CorelDRAW.